# Python Mulitple For loops with common else

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

my code at the minute has 2 lists `Exercise` and `Weight`. These both contain the contents of generated entry boxes. When the lists are being saved to the database I need to make sure that no empty boxes are submitted, to solve this I am writing a validation algorithm to check if any of the boxes are empty, this is the code so far:

```
for item in Exercise:
    if item == '':
        self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
        connection.commit()

for item in Weight:
    if item == '':
        self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
        connection.commit()
else:
    values = zip(Exercise, Weight, ID)
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Exercises(Exercise, Weight, ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", values)        
    connection.commit()
```

My problem is that I have two for loops which both have the same `else`. However I do not know how to create this so the `else` is activated if either of both of the items in the list are empty.

Comment: The thing is that you don't wanna dublicate an "else" am i right ?

Comment: No as if I duplicate the else then it will still insert into the database if one of the items is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you test the same conditions on the items of Exercise and Weight, you could do it like this:

```
from itertools import chain

if any(item == '' for item in chain(Exercise, Weight)):
    self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
    connection.commit()

else:
    values = zip(Exercise, Weight, ID)
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Exercises(Exercise, Weight, ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", values)        
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to use the `any` function:

```
if any(i == '' for i in Exercise) or any(i == '' for i in Weight):
    self.CreateError....
else:
    values = zip(...
```

The downside to this approach is that it may not be the most scalable if you have to iterate through even more collections (in addition to Exercise, Weight, etc.). However, a variation of this style could remedy that (EDIT: look at @Thierry Lathuille's answer)

Comment: I actually prefer @Thierry's variation to this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any` here

```
if any(item == '' for item in Exercise) or any(item == '' for item in Weight):
    self.CreateError.configure(fg = "red")
else:
    values = zip(Exercise, Weight, ID)
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Exercises(Exercise, Weight, ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", values)        
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Sorry, missed @sshashank124  answer

Comment: Also (just for the sake of DRY), `connection.commit()` can be written only once (outside the `if-else`)